# Issues with nesting components after upgrading to newer versions of TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I recently upgraded from TypeScript 2.1 and with all of the newer versions I started getting the error below with all of my React Components that follow the pattern in my example. This pattern of nesting components didn't used to cause any problem before the upgrade.

**Component #1:**

```
interface ISpinnerProps{
    showGlobalSpinner: boolean;
}

class SpinnerClass extends React.Component<ISpinnerProps, undefined> {
    render() {
         return (
         // Some markup
         )
    }
}

export const Spinner = connect((state: State) => {
  return {
    showGlobalSpinner: selectors.showGlobalSpinner(state),
  }
})(SpinnerClass)
```

**Component #2:**

```
interface IProps {
   loginStatus: fb.LoginStatus
}


class AppClass extends React.Component<IProps, undefined> {
    render() {
         return (
         // Some markup
         <Spinner/> // Error is thrown here.
         )
    }
}
export const App = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(AppClass)
```

This causes the error:
`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ISpinnerProps>'. Property 'showGlobalSpinner' is missing in type '{}`

The compiler wants me to set the properties of the children in the parent but these properties are handled by Redux. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Simply mark the prop as optional with `?`  `showGlobalSpinner: ?booelan;` I think that would do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is separate your props into props and actions mapped from redux (IMappedProps and IMappedActions) and props that you expect to be passed into your component from a parent component (IOwnProps).

Then in your connect function you are able to specify which props are which.

```
export default connect<IMappedProps, IMappedActions, IOwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDistpatchToProps)(SpinnerClass);
```

In your case, the spinner component only has one prop that is mapped from redux. Your connect function could look like this:

```
export default connect<ISpinnerProps, null, null>(mapStateToProps, null)(SpinnerClass);
```

Note for clarity I'd suggest renaming ISpnnerProps to IMappedProps.

For further reference see the react-redux typescript definition - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts

Comment: This is a great answer Nick. As I mentioned, I had this problem in many components using this pattern. And this approach solves the problems for components which have some State and Actions connected. However for components like Spinner, I cannot declare null for Actions:
`(mapStateToProps, null)`  I'm getting this error:
message: 'Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapDispatchToPropsParam<any, null>

Comment: @cinnaroll45, No worries, happy to help. Could you check that you have the latest versions of @types/react-redux and react-redux?

Comment: At the moment the project has: `@types/react-redux: 4.4.41` and `react-redux: 5.0.5`. The component is here:
https://pastebin.com/wCZTqhfz

Comment: @cinnaroll45, try this instead `export const GlobalSpinner = connect<IProps, null, null>(mapStateToProps)(GlobalSpinnerClass)`

Comment: I've tried that earlier, that fixes the error on that component but than the main error in the question comes back in the parent component which is using <GlobalSpinner>.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16954. For now you could downgrade your types definition for react-redux to `"@types/react-redux": "4.4.40",`

Comment: I'm following the updates in that repo and you're right, it's an issue with the types. Your solution works flawlessly with components that have both state and action passed via connect. Hopefully they'll fix the types so it'll work with passing `null` for actions.